# Unable to find string in Java File

Tags: java

I have a Java program that works without issue for searching most strings but for some reason I am unable to have it find the below ina  file which I know appears in the file. I am obviously trying to locate a certain element that has the value of 999 but i am unable to do so. Again this works for other strings just not the one below.

```
   for(int i=0;i< inputFile.length;i++)
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile[i]));
            try {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    countLine++;
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");

                    for (String word : words) {
                        if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                            count++;
                            countBuffer++;
                        }
                    }

                    if(countBuffer > 0)
                    {
                        countBuffer = 0;
                        lineNumber += countLine + ",";
                    }

                }
                br.close();
```

Comment: Post your code you already have

Comment: How are you searching?  Are you using regular expressions?

Comment: are you sure that file contains this string?

Comment: I'm guessing your XML contains white-space.

Comment: I am sure it contains elements with that value.UPDATED POST again this code works without issue searching for other strings in the file.

Comment: you removed the string which u are unable to find in the file...

Comment: The way you are searching (using `split` and `equals`), your search word must be surrounded by blanks or you won't find it.

Comment: @ammoQ thanks. Can you give an example of how I should be searching.

Comment: Since you want to count occurences, a simple (though maybe not most efficient) way would be using `String.indexOf` like that: `int idx=0; while ((idx=line.indexOf(inputSearch,idx))>=0) { count+; countBuffer++; idx+=inputSearch.length(); }` within the read loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and something like -

```
String toMatch = "<element>999</element>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">\\s*999\\s*<");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(toMatch);
int count = 0;
int start = 0;
while (start < toMatch.length() && match.find(start)) {
  // Pattern found.
  start = match.regionEnd() + 1;
  count++;
}
```